# Gradient text in 2 lines on iPhone 13, does not display text in the 2nd line

Tags: css, iphone, safari, gradient, linear-gradients

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiY5q.jpg)

There is a display block, we tried different solutions with stacked overflow, nothing helps, and on many iPhones it looks fine, but for some reason the 1st specifically has this bug. Please tell me what could be the matter, we will be grateful for any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid we won't have a clue what is going on without seeing relevant code. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example